# Prove that for all natural numbers $n \geq 2$, $n^2 \geq n + 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove that for all natural numbers $n \geq 2$, $n^2 \geq n + 2$.

In solving this proof, I tried two methods, first working backward and then using the contradiction approach. i wish to solve this proof directly or using a contradiction however I am stuck on how to verify it for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Maybe try induction.

Comment: Cute question.  ***endorsed, +1***

Comment: If $~n^2 \geq (n+2)~$ and $~n \geq 2,~$ does this imply that $\color{red}{(n+1)^2 \geq ([n+1] + 2)}~$ ?

Comment: $n^2 \ge n + 2\iff n^2-n = n(n-1) \ge 2$.  And as $n\ge 2$ we have $n-1 \ge 1$ so $n(n-1) \ge 2\times 1 = 2$ so $n^2-n = n(n-1)\ge 2$ and $n^2 \ge n + 2$.  Contradiction.  If $n^2 < n+2$ but $n > 0$ then $n < 1 + \frac 2n$.  If $n\ge 2$ then $\frac 2n \le 1$ so we have $n < 1 + \frac 2n \le 1+1 = 2$ so $n < 2$ which is a condracition.  A clever way is $n^2 \ge n+ 1 \iff n^2-1 \ge n+1 \iff (n+1)(n-1) \ge n+1$ and as $n+1\ge 3 > 0$ we can divide both sides to get $n-1\ge 1$ which is true.  ... If stuck we know that if $n>1$ then $n^2 >n$ but by how much? $n^2=n\times n\ge 2\times n=n+n\ge n+2$.

Answer (score 5):

for $n\geq2$, $n-2\geq 0$ and $n+1 > 0$

then

$(n-2)(n+1) \geq 0$

$n^2-n-2 \geq 0$

$n^2 \geq n+2$

Answer (score 1):

For

$n \ge 2, \tag 1$

$n^2 = nn \ge 2n = n + n \ge n + 2. \tag 2$

***Generalization:***

If

$n \ge m \ge 2, \tag 3$

then

$n^2 = nn \ge mn = \displaystyle \sum_1^m n = n + \sum_1^{m - 1} n \ge n + m. \tag 4$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve for the sake of curiosity. For $n\geq 2$, one gets:
\begin{align*}
\frac{n(n - 1)}{2} = 1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n- 1 \geq 1 \Rightarrow \frac{n(n- 1)}{2} \geq 1 \Rightarrow n^{2} - n \geq 2 \Rightarrow n^{2} \geq n + 2
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

complete the square.

$n^2 - n \ge 2 \implies (n-\frac{1}{2})^2 \ge \frac{9}{4} \implies n \ge 2$ which is true.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the quickest way:

If $n \ge 2$ then $n^2 = n \times n \ge n\times 2 = n + n \ge n + 2$.

If that was too slick:

We now that $n^2 > n$ in general.  But by how much and when?  $n^2 - n = n(n-1)$.  As $n \ge 2$ and $n-1 \ge 1$ then $n^2 - n \ge 2\times 1$ and $n^2 \ge n + 2$.

A cute thing happens when we try a proof by contradiction.

Suppose $n^2 < n + 2$ and $n\ge 2$.  If we divide both sides by $n > 0$ we get $n < 1 + \frac 2n$.  But as $n \ge 2$ we have $\frac 2n \le 1$ so $n < 1 + \frac 2n \le 1 + 1 =2$ so $n < 2$ which is a contradiction.

A creative way:  $n^2 = n^2$ and $n^2 - 1 = (n+1)(n-1)$.  And $n-1 \ge 1$ we have $n^2 -1 = (n+1)(n-1) \ge (n+1)\times 1 = (n+1)$ so $n^2 = n + 2$.

And there's always figuring out necessary and sufficient and/or equivalent statements.

$n^2 \ge n + 2 \iff n^2 - n \ge 2 \iff n(n-1) \ge 2$ and is that true?  As $n \ge 2$ and $n-1\ge 1$ it is.

Then there is always induction:

If $n = 2$ then $n^2 =4$ and $n + 2 = 4$ so $n^2 \ge n+2$.

If we assume that $n^2 \ge n+2$ then we have $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1$ and as $n^2 \ge n+2$ we have $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1 \ge (n+2) + 2n+ 1 = 3n + 3$ but is $3n +3 \ge 2(n+1) + 2$?  Well,  $3n + 3 = 2(n+1) + (n+1)$ and as $n \ge 2$ we have $2(n+1) +(n+1)\ge 2(n+1) + 3 > 2(n+1) + 2$.

[i.e.  $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1 \ge (2n+2) + (2n +1)=2(n+1) + (2n+1)> 2(n+1) + 2$]

So our induction step holds.